# nextjs 14 App router multiple rendering tsx files in 1 folder

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am upgrading from nextjs 12 to 14 tailwind/typescript app router.

I have directory called /test/ with the files:layout.tsx,judging.tsx,listings.tsx,page.tsx,

When I go to test/judging I want it to pull up the test/judging.tsx. Currently if I go to http://localhost/test/ the default page comes up, if I go to localhost/test/judging I get 404

Now I realize that under test I could make a folder called judging and then I would have the path test/judging.

My question is this, if I have 50 files in the /test/ folder do I have to make 50 subfolders in test to get the routing for them to be rendered? This doesnt sound right to me.

In version 12 everyone was using the _app.js and get layout in the index.js to have all the pages displayed. Is there a similar technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the error you have made. You have created a folder with the name `test` which has a file `judging.tsx` that you want to access.

**App Router**

If you are using `app router` all you have to do is create a folder in your `test` directory named `judging` and in the `judging` folder create a file `page.tsx` with `export default`

**Note:** If you are creating dynamic route just name the folder `[judging]` with `page.tsx` in it.

**Page Router**

If you are using `page router` all you have to do is create a folder in your `test` directory named `judging` and in the `judging` folder create a file `index.tsx` with `export default`

**Note:** If you are creating dynamic route just name the file `[judging].tsx` in `test` folder

Comment: After exploring multiple solutions I just created the routes with folders.